# Property XXX does not exit on type 'Computed' using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3

The code runs and in the console for the browser prints out true.  However on my local server I am getting an error `Property 'authorities' does not exist on type 'Computed'.`
I am new to Typescript and Vuex. I checked and isAdmin is an object that has authorities that is an array

Here is my code

```
export default {
    name: "UserSettingsTabs",
      computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      preferences: 'tab/preferences',
      administrations: 'tab/administrations',
      isAdmin: 'auth/currentUser'
    }),
    isUserAdmin() : boolean{
      console.log(this.isAdmin.authorities.includes('Admin'));
      return this.isAdmin.authorities.includes('Admin');
    }   }, }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `mapGetters` which resolves `isAdmin` as a `<Computed>`

This is discussed [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/109) with some possible solutions

If you're ok with simple solution, you could use `this.isAdmin as IIsAdmin` with your custom interface or type.

You could also use a computed that pulls the value from vuex instead of using mapGetters.

Comment: also, I wonder if pinia solves this issue more elegantly   https://pinia.esm.dev/core-concepts/getters.html#usage-with-the-options-api